# Undesired auto expansion with company-mode and python-mode

Tags: python, company-mode

I am using company-mode and python-mode (note the same issue does not happen with python.el) and something about the combination is causing emacs to automatically expand at point. For example, if I type "R" it will expand immediately to "REDISTRIBUTING", it seems to be looking in all of my buffers for dabbrevs.

Minimal working init is below. How can I disable this behaviour or at least figure out where the bug lies so that I can report it. I am using emacs 24.4 on OSX (Yamamoto Mitsuharu's port). I would also be interested in knowing whether others can replicate this.

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
 (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
 (add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

Comment: With "expand immediately", do you mean "inserts that text", as opposed to showing the text and requiring TAB or RET to insert it?

Comment: @JorgenSchäfer Yes. It simply inserts the text.

Comment: Very strange. I assume as your minimal config includes python-mode that it does not happen with the built-in python.el? Reporting a bug with company-mode would probably my next step – though I have absolutely no idea what might be going on there.

Comment: Yeah it is odd, thanks for looking into it. The behaviour isn't repeated with the built in python.el. Were you able to repeat the behaviour?

Comment: No, but I do not have python-mode here, either (it conflicts with other installed packages, so I can't easily test, either).

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for checking. I will think about submitting a bug report.

Comment: @noaham: Did you ever find a fix for this bug?

Comment: @runejuhl: Does using the inbuilt python.el instead count as a fix? :) Unfortunately I haven't. Are you able to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: I had the similar issue but not with python-mode, with org-mode instead. I somehow managed to solve it by reinstalling the company from gnu channel, replacing the one from melpa.